# nested select queries - mysql sakila database

Tags: mysql

I have found the minimum postode for each district, and now want to find the maximum of all of these district postcode minimums. Im getting stuck with how to do max while keeping the other parts in tact.

```
select 
   district, 
   postal_code, 
   min(postal_code) from address
group by district
having district is not null and district !="" and postal_code>0
order by district;
```

[image: result]

Comment: You are selecting the `postal_code` column, which is not in your `GROUP BY` list.  You should fix this.

Answer (score 1):

If only the `max(min_postal_code)` is needed, use the following statement.

```
select max(min_postal_code) 
from (
    select district, min(postal_code) AS min_postal_code
    from address
    where district is not null and district !="" and postal_code>0
    group by district
    order by district) t
```

If the district name with the `MAX(min_postal_code)` is also need. Use the following statement.

```
select * 
from (select district, min(postal_code) AS min_postal_code
    from address
    where district is not null and district !="" and postal_code>0
    group by district) t
where t.min_postal_code = 
(
    select max(min_postal_code) 
    from (select district, min(postal_code) AS min_postal_code
        from address
        where district is not null and district !="" and postal_code>0
        group by district) t2
);
```

Comment: yes this works! can you please explain the t on the last line (just started using MySql)

Comment: what if i want to also select the corresponding district name?
I tried this:
select district, max(min_postal_code) 
from (
    select district, min(postal_code) AS min_postal_code
    from address
    where district is not null and district !="" and postal_code>0
    group by district
    order by district) t;

but the district name im getting is wrong (the max value is right though

Comment: Updated the post. try again.